# get column names to array

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to get colum names to array in System.Data.DataTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

```
var columnNames = myDataTable.Columns.
         Cast<DataColumn>().
         Select(c => c.ColumnName).
         ToArray();
```

Comment: @Harsh `myDataTable.Columns.Cast < DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this

```
using System.Linq;

// ... //

var columnsArray = dtObj.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();
```